# Perform XML Transformation on Existing Azure Webapp

Tags: xml, powershell, transform, azure-web-app-service, octopus-deploy

I have an existing web-app deployed to Azure. This is a 'vanilla' release that I then want to add customer specific customisations to via additional dll's and config changes.

I've been trying to use the 'Deploy Azure Web App' step in Octopus Deploy to push out these additional dll's and config changes via an XML transformation file, however it doesn't seem to work as the transformation step is run on the Octopus server and not on Azure where the web.config file is.

Ive looked at using the PostDeploy step also but this seems to have the same problem.

Is this possible using Octopus Deploy or something else, like a Powershell script that uses the Azure API? Or possibly download the web.confg file from Azure, perform the transformation then re-upload it?

Answer (score 1):

Your source of truth for your app including code and configuration is not the version you have living on the Azure instance.

Pushing a new version of the code or configuration should be pulling from a local package, whether that be produced manually or via a build process (TeamCity, VSTS, Jenkins etc). You would then push that package to your Octopus Deploy server and create a release.

This release represents the state of your code, configuration and any Octopus variables at the time the release is created. This is also the copy of the web.config that you would run your XML transformation on as part of the deployment in the "Deploy to Azure Web App" step.

By keeping your source of truth away from the running instance in Azure, means that you can repeat your deployment, either because there was a problem on the running instance or you need to create a hundred new copies.

Comment: That is mostly how it currently works, however the release is split into two parts. One for a 'vanilla' release of the application, which is what currently lives on Azure. It can be customised per customer however,, which is the second part that it overlaid with additional dll's and config transformations. Are you saying that these two parts should be combined into one 'source of truth'?

Comment: For that scenario you probably want to use [tenants](https://octopus.com/docs/guides/multi-tenant-deployments/multi-tenant-deployment-guide). You may also need to change your build process, depending on how your code is structured to handle per-customer customization. With a multi-tenant deployment, you can scope process actions to different tenants or include variables with their values different per tenant, or you may need to have multiple deployment processes.

Comment: OK thanks, so merging the customisation into the build process rather than the 'two step' approach is the way to go?

Comment: It really depends on how it all works, as I said before. Your build process could build one package per customer, or your deployment process could create a customised deployment per customer, using tenants in Octopus Deploy.